# Cake 3.x How do I trigger a bake template in another vendor?

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, cakephp-bake

1. cake version: 3.1.2
2. crud version: 4.2.0

Inside vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task, there is a `ControllerTask.php` code [here](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/214b2f13309f760f5cd6b9d502bd2437f7a9cd87/src/Shell/Task/ControllerTask.php)

Inside vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Template/Bake/Controller, there is a `controller.ctp` code [here](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/214b2f13309f760f5cd6b9d502bd2437f7a9cd87/src/Template/Bake/Controller/controller.ctp)

Inside vendor/friendsofcake/crud/src/Template/Bake/Controller, there is a `controller.ctp` code [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud/blob/6bb4a2d14e809e53aed1a28d25cbcec6f5304ca9/src/Template/Bake/Controller/controller.ctp)

My question is how do I execute the controller bake template inside a different vendor without copy and pasting the code into my App/Template/Bake as suggested by http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-new-bake-command-options?

I would like to be able to do something like `bin/cake bake crud.controller users` for e.g.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
bin/cake bake controller users --theme Crud
```